# cookie value not shown

Tags: php, cookies

This is my code:

```
    <?php 
    $friendid = 10;
    $friendname = "enco";

    $max=count($_COOKIE['rooms']); 
    $i = $max + 1;

    setcookie("rooms[$i]['type']", "1on1", time() + 3600, "/", ".mywebsite.com");
    setcookie("rooms[$i]['name']", $friendname, time() + 3600, "/", ".mywebsite.com");
?>
```

The code below is in another page:

```
<?php
    $max=count($_COOKIE['rooms']); 

$k = 0;
for($k = 0; $k<$max; $k++) {
    echo "Cookie 1 show: " . $_COOKIE['rooms'][$k]['type'] . "<br /><br />";
    echo "Cookie 2 show: " . $_COOKIE['rooms'][$k]['name'] . "<br /><br />"; 
    }
    ?>
```

But it does not work. 
When I try to echo the cookies like I did in the example above, nothing appears.

My question is: 
Are these structures correct:

```
setcookie("rooms[$i]['type']", "1on1", time() + 3600, "/", ".mywebsite.com");
setcookie("rooms[$i]['name']", $friendname, time() + 3600, "/", ".mywebsite.com");
```

in order to show these in another page (not in the same page where the cookies are written):

```
echo "Cookie 1 show: " . $_COOKIE['rooms'][$i]['type'] . "<br /><br />";
echo "Cookie 2 show: " . $_COOKIE['rooms'][$i]['name'] . "<br /><br />";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

PHP's superglobals _GET, _POST, _REQUEST, _COOKIE are all created at script startup, and then **NEVER** modified by PHP for the duration of the script's execution.

The cookie you create with `setcookie()` will therefore NOT be available in _COOKIE until the **NEXT** time you run this code.

Comment: Yes, you can't set a cookie and read it during the same script

Comment: I understand. but that is not problem. i wrote the codes to read the cookies in the same script to tell you that nothing is shown.

Comment: please, have a look at the question again. i modified it

Comment: do a `var_dump($_COOKIE)` and you'll see exactly what you're dealing with.